# Evaluating $\int\frac{3x+1}{2x^2-2x+3}dx$

Tags: integration

Sorry I don't know how to use MathJaX but i've got a problem here that nobody seems to be able to explain to me.

$$\int{3x + 1 \over 2x^{2} - 2x + 3}\,{\rm d}x.$$

It seems rather simple at first glance, perhaps factorise the bottom equation but I can't seem to do it. I know you can't factorise the bottom equation. The answer i'm given is something long and very different from what I know.

I don't like coming here for simple maths problems but alas, I have no choice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

As $$\frac{3x+1}{2x^2-2x+3}=\frac{6x+2}{4x^2-4x+6}=\frac{6x+2}{(2x-1)^2+(\sqrt5)^2}$$

using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) $$2x-1=\sqrt5\tan\phi$$

Comment: Firstly, how did you think of doubling everything and then splitting it up to form a Trig substitution? Secondly, I have substituted √5tanϕ in but still am at a loss as to what to do? I am currently sitting on int(6x+2)/(5tan^2ϕ+5)dx although I have a feeling I may have something wrong :P

Comment: @PejmanPoh, $$2x-1=\sqrt5\tan\phi\implies 2\ dx=\sqrt5\sec^2\phi\ d\phi$$ 

So, we have $$\int\frac{3x+1}{2x^2-2x+3}\ dx=\int\frac{3(\sqrt5\tan\phi+1)+2}{5\sec^2\phi}\frac{\sqrt5\sec^2\phi}2\ d\phi=\frac32\tan\phi\ d\phi+\frac{\sqrt5}2$$

Comment: Ah I see. I would have never gotten that and give me that question again a few months and I would never think of doing that but I understand what you did. Thanks